# Open a webpage in flex application

Tags: html, apache-flex

How can I open a web (example `www.cnn.com`) in a Flex application?

Answer (score 7):

I understand that you are trying to open an url in the default system browser.Please try this.

```
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.adobe.com/");
            //To open in a new tab
            navigateToURL(urlRequest,_blank);
            //To open on top of the same page
            navigateToURL(urlRequest,_top);
```

If you are looking to open an url within a Flex application you check [here](http://www.deitte.com/archives/2006/08/finally_updated.htm)

Comment: Please note, the _blank must be quoted, because it is a String var.  i.e. - navigateToURL(urlRequest, "_blank");  see here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf626ae-7fe8.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ea7