# mx:HTML window - data scraping a php page?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, html-parsing

I have a **Flex mx:HTML** component which uses an html window to display html data from 3rd party website.

let's call the page:

### http://www.company.com/page.php (not a _real page (duh))

There is alot of "trash" displayed.

I used "***Firebug***" to inspect the webpage elements.

I see that the section of the page I want to display is:

**/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]**

or, to put it a another way:

**html body.landing div#content-bg div#content-wrap div#content div.main**

my question:

Is there a way to access **this section of the page only**, especially since it is "rendered" using PHP (which I have no knowledge or understanding of)?

(I will **NOT** be using PHP to gather this info)

many thanks!

Mark

Comment: It doesn't make a difference what language was used to generate the HTML. It's not a 'PHP page' if you don't have access to the PHP code, it's an HTML page. Anyhow, what you need is an ActionScript DOM or XML parser.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to Flex [IFrame](http://code.google.com/p/flex-iframe/) which enables HTML Browsing in Flex apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965123/open-a-webpage-in-flex-application/4965521#4965521) URL.

Comment: kbgn27 - I already know how to display html in an mx:html window - what I wasn't clear about (I now realize) is that is part of an AIR app. I'm wanting to get the particular subset of the page mentioned above