# How to enable (open in a new tab) for LinkButton?

Tags: apache-flex

I would like to enable the (Open in a new tab) option when a user right clicks a mx:LinkButton, take the address that linkbutton is supposed to go to and allow the user to click on (open in a new tab) and get to that address in a new tab. Is there an easy way to do that.

Note: I would like for that to apply to every linkbutton created (becomes a default behaviour of LinkButtons) and NOT to a specific linkbutton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](http://www.huyler.net/flexblog/2009/02/02/taking-control-of-right-click-in-adobe-flex/) site. It worked for my button, may be you can extend it for your linkbutton.

To open a webpage please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965123/open-a-webpage-in-flex-application/4965521#4965521) answer.